# Learn French from music — resources?

Tags: ressources, apprentissage, musique

I am looking for resources for learning French from music.

(Not just adequate music, but the totality of resources, like written French Lyrics, translation, English version etc.)

Comment: IMHO, learning french from music is a really bad idea. Just like learning french from poems. This is because sometimes songs are composed from only parts of sentences, sometimes they're omitting words intentionally, or they use unusual words so that it fits with the music or because they want to give more than one meaning to the text. Bad idea.

Comment: I learned a big deal from listening to Lara Fabian... She pronounces the words one by one and very clearly, and the lyrics are almost always grammatically sound. https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCHr44OlK408Wyotta7qMp7g The good news is also that Lara Fabian is relatively internationally well-known and it's really easy to find translations of her songs on the internet.

Comment: Jacques Brel and Babara. Good diction, but might be difficult to go into the meaning if you don't have a lot of vocabulary.

Comment: J'ai oublié Léo Ferré.

Comment: Georges Brassens. Enfin, tous cites par @cl-r.

Answer (score 3):

J'ajouterais aux chanteurs et chanteuses listés en commentaire :

Georges Brassens, Claude Nougaro, Jean Ferrat, Gilbert Bécaud, Joe Dassin, Charles Aznavour, Édith Piaf, Serge Gainsbourg, Juliette Gréco, Julien Clair, Charles Trenet ...

comme principaux représentants de *'La chanson à texte'* du XX<sup>e</sup> siècle.

En plus d'une bonne diction, chacun a son répertoire, son talent, sa sensibilité, son timbre, sa 'petite  musique' qui le rend reconnaissable immédiatement.

D'abord, la mélodie permet souvent de mieux mémoriser les paroles, et vous apprendrez le français à l'oreille, les tournures usuelles ou intéressantes, souvent les mots du parlé  'normal' sans  vous encombrer l'esprit de règles grammaticales (que peu de français sont capables de vous expliquer).

C'est une très bonne approche pour être dans le bain, pour assimiler la prosodie, le phrasé, le rythme, la structure des phrases qui vous retrouverez dans vos futures rencontres.

C'est un bon moyen de comprendre la vie de tous les jours, mais cela nécessite aussi des connaissances hors du domaine de la chanson pour avoir une conversation dans un langage soutenu.

Comment: Je mets un bémol à la bonne diction de Piaf, Gainsbourg et Gréco. loin de critiquer leur talent, il y a des chansons dont je ne comprends pas les paroles.

Answer (score 2):

Essayez **[Grand Corps Malade](http://www.youtube.com/user/GrandCorpsOfficiel)**. C’est le nom de scène de Fabien Marsaud. Il fait du [slam](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slam_%28po%C3%A9sie%29). Ses textes sont dits et non chantés, accompagnés d’une mélodie minimaliste en arrière-plan.

Answer (score 1):

Sur le site de TV5MONDE, il y a une bonne rubrique éducative avec des chansons francophones. À ce moment ils offrent 175 chansons avec les paroles et des activités pédagogiques.

**http://enseigner.tv5monde.com/collection/paroles-de-clips**

Answer (score 0):

Here's from a non-native learner of French like you:
Try Gilbert Bécaud, Alizée, Joe Dassin (in that order). I am sure you will learn (better if they are subtitled) as well as enjoy! But one must choose the songs carefully as some might be easier than others.
Let me know about your experience and I will recommend more.

Answer (score 0):

Debussy: Pelleas et Melisande (original recording by Irene Joachim, conductor Roger Desormieres)

Answer (score 0):

One website that I found helpful is http://lyricstraining.com.  You can watch contemporary and classic videos with the lyrics.  You can learn lyrics or just sing karaoke-style.

It's not just French, but also other languages.

Answer (score -1):

I propose you to listen to "Les Enfoirés" (French for "The Tossers" or "The Bastards"), is the name given to the singers and performers in the yearly charity concert for the Restaurants du Cœur (Les Restos du Cœur).

The song interpretations are basically taken from the francophone repertoire but with a number of international songs. Songs from more than 300 artists, French and other, were interpreted.

Mostly cheerful songs and the lyrics are generally very clear. Easy to find the songs with english subtitles.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B5mzzz13grk&hd=1

Hope it can helps!

Answer (score -2):

I recently stumbled upon this website (link below). Have been picking up many words/expression phrases from it. Plus the songs are great!

http://frenchforprocrastinators.blogspot.ca/